# How does memory alignment work for a reference to a struct in C++?

Tags: c++

I made a discovery which I was not aware of when casting a buffer to a struct reference which itself includes a data buffer.

I think this example is best explained with a code example:

```
struct myStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  char data[1];
};

#define TB_SIZE 5
char data[TB_SIZE] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5};


void f(struct myStruct& dest) {
  dest.a = 33;
  memcpy(dest.data, data, TB_SIZE);
}

int main() {
  char buf[100];
  f(reinterpret_cast<struct myStruct&>(buf[0]));
  struct myStruct castStruct = reinterpret_cast<struct myStruct&>(buf[0]);

  printf("Src Values\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < TB_SIZE; ++i) {
    printf("0x%02x, ", data[i]);
  }
  printf("\nActual\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < TB_SIZE; ++i) {
    printf("0x%02x, ", castStruct.data[i]);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

The output from this simple program is:

```
Src Values
0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 
Actual
0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x00,
```

After casting the buffer to a struct reference, when i print the data buffer inside the struct, it seems that we have lost the last value, ie. castStruct[4].

Now I guess this has with alignment issues with structs to do but I am not really sure why. If I instead change all reference to pointers the program works as expected, Also if I just have one integer in myStruct before the data[] field the program also works as expected. So my question is simply, how does memory alignment work for a reference to a struct in C++?

Comment: So...many...nasal...demons....

Comment: Anyway, `myStruct::data` is an array of a single `char`, so copying a `myStruct` only guarantees copying that one `char`. Looks like in your case it happens to have 3 bytes of padding and that the copying also happens to copy the padding, so you get the first 4 bytes.

Comment: Did you intend `castStruct` to be a reference? It isn't one.

Comment: The undefined behaviour in this program made my cat pregnant, and I don't even have a cat (with apologies to Marshall Clow for stealing his joke)

Comment: A reference is implemented as a pointer under the hood.  As you found out, it takes 4 bytes in a 32-bit program.  Drop the &.

Comment: The behaviour's got nothing to do with references vs. pointers.  Elemental's answer's correct in explaining why you could only have *expected* (if the rest of the program didn't have Undefined Behaviour which invalidates all bets)  `castStruct.data[1]` to be copied, but you're quite reasonably seeing `sizeof(myStruct)` bytes copied.  Other as-of-yet unmentioned issues: your `buf` may not be aligned properly for `int`s, so `dest.a` could SIGBUS on some architectures, and at least the last - and as many as 4 - of your `buf[]` elements are being printed uninitialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think this behaviour is expected - in fact you get more than you should reasonably expect, in this line:

```
struct myStruct castStruct = reinterpret_cast<struct myStruct&>(buf[0]);
```

You copy the contents of the nasty buffer into a new struct castStruct - the compiler only guarantees that the actual elements of the struct are copied - specifically it only copies a single character array.
What you would expect is to only get the first character (as it happens because of alignment an extra few bytes are also copied). 
Note that castStruct.data[2] refers to unallocated, undefined memory as you have copied the struct away from your first buffer.